# How do I remove carriage returns with Ruby without replacing it with "-" or blank space

Tags: ruby

I want to remove carriage returns from:

```
"LIC_001  \r\n      ,\r\n        LIC_002  \r\n      "
```

I want the value to be like:

```
"LIC_001 , LIC_002  "
```

I tried:

```
"LIC_001  \r\n      ,\r\n        LIC_002  \r\n      ".gsub!("\r\n", " - ")
```

Please suggest how I can do this.

Comment: please, add `ruby-on-rails` tag, if its Rails question.

Comment: I had added it but around 2-3 people edited it .

Comment: it would be simply : `str.tr("\r\n ","")` using [String#tr](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
"LIC_001  \r\n      ,\r\n        LIC_002  \r\n      ".squish
#=> "LIC_001 , LIC_002"
```

Comment: @kirti Although that wasnt in the original question, you can do `arr.map(&:squish)` for an array of those kind of strings.

Comment: arr.map(&:squish) why its not changing into two elements... both of the values are on same index.

Comment: `squish` can't change the index af anything, it's only modifying a string. Your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: ya i am checking... Thanks for your Help

Comment: @Eric, Originally this question was with `Rails` tag :)

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "LIC_001  \r\n      ,\r\n        LIC_002  \r\n      "  
str.split(',').map(&:squish)
# => ["LIC_001", "LIC_002"]
str.split(',').map(&:squish).join(" , ")
# => "LIC_001 , LIC_002"
```

Comment: Having a space in front of the comma is just strange though.

Comment: Sorry I was confusing strip and squish. @EricDuminil

Answer (score 1):

You could replace multiple whitespaces by a space with [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), and remove trailing and leading spaces with [`strip!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-strip-21) :

```
"LIC_001  \r\n      ,\r\n        LIC_002  \r\n      ".gsub(/\s+/,' ').strip!
# "LIC_001 , LIC_002"
```

Both methods are standard Ruby.

If your string contains unicode whitespaces, you can use

```
"LIC_001  \r\n      ,\r\n        LIC_002  \r\n      ".gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,' ').strip!
# "LIC_001 , LIC_002"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split/join and a regex for this:

```
str = "LIC_001  \r\n      ,\r\n        LIC_002  \r\n      "
puts str.split(/[\n\r, ]+/).join(" , ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
"LIC_001  \r\n      ,\r\n        LIC_002  \r\n      ".gsub!("\r\n", "")
```

If so, explain why it doesn't give you the desired result...

Comment: its removing carriage returns but not white spaces with the values